# If the number of points of two elliptic curves are close enough, then they are equal?

Tags: reference-request, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

$\newcommand{\Q}{\Bbb Q}
\newcommand{\N}{\Bbb N}
\newcommand{\R}{\Bbb R}
\newcommand{\Z}{\Bbb Z}
\newcommand{\C}{\Bbb C}
\newcommand{\F}{\Bbb F}
$
On page 23 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.3972.pdf#page=23), one can read:

> For example, if $E, E'$ are elliptic curves over $\Q$, then $|N_E(p)-N_{E'}(p)| \leq 1.4 \sqrt p$ for all but finitely many $p$ implies $N_E(p) = N_{E'}(p)$ for all $p$.

Here $N_X(q)$ is the cardinality of $X(\F_q)$ where $X$ is a scheme of finite type over $\Z$ and $q$ is a prime power, and $E,E'$ are supposed to be given by a Weierstrass equation with integer coefficients.

I would like to know why this statement is true, and to have further references proving this fact.

---

I'm really surprised about the claim above, because it implies in particular the amazing statement

(A) : if $N_E(p) = N_{E'}(p)$ for almost all $p$, then $N_E(p) = N_{E'}(p)$ for all $p$ (even at bad primes).

I think that $N_E(p) = N_{E'}(p)$ implies $N_E(p^2) = N_{E'}(p^2)$, so that $(A)$ might follow from theorem 1 in *[Strong multiplicity one for the Selberg class](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k57326058/f319.item.r)* (Murty & Murty), by modularity (possibly using [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98466), to relate local $L$-factors to the number of points of $E$ at bad primes – we need to work with Weierstrass models, as mentioned in the comments there). Maybe we can also use Falting's theorem (about Tate's conjecture) together with Chebotarev's density theorem?

But this is anyway very far from the quoted statement above, which only assume a bound $1.4 \sqrt p$ on the difference. 
According to exericse 3) in §8.4.4 and remark 5) in §6.3.1 of *Lectures on $N_X(p)$* by Jean-Pierre Serre, Sato–Tate conjecture implies that $|N_E(p) - N_{E'}(p)|$ is bounded when $p$ runs over the primes (and we could replace $1.4 \sqrt p$ by $1.99\sqrt p$). Still this is not sufficient to apply the theorem 1 cited above.

Related (but different) : [(1)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3352).

Comment: The result you quote above follows from Theorem A.1 in the same paper, which in turn is proved in pages 24 and 25. Are you saying you are not convinced by the proof they provide of Theorem A.1?

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo : thank you for your comment. I have to look more closely to this statement. But it seems to me that they should assume $|N_E(p)-N_{E'}(p)| \leq 1.4$ instead of $|N_E(p)-N_{E'}(p)| \leq 1.4 \sqrt p$. Am I missing something?

Comment: I believe it is an issue of normalization. In their notation, traces are normalized. See the proof of Prop 3.3 where they refer to this, when they say that to apply Theorem 2.2 first you have to write an analytically normalized L-function.

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo : ok, so just to be sure, the quoted statement (with $|N_E(p)-N_{E'}(p)| \leq 1.4 \sqrt p$ and $N_E(p)$ being the number of points of $E$ mod $p$) is indeed true? I was confused because after the statement of theorem A.1, they are writing a condition $|tr(A(\pi_p)) - tr(A(\pi'_p))| < 1.4$, but I'm not sure what are the Satake parameters of the automorphic representation attached to a modular form $f = f_E$.

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo : according to theorem 5.6 [here](http://math.arizona.edu/~jeremybooher/expos/adelic_mod_forms.pdf), the sum of the Satake parameters of $\pi_{f_E, p}$ should be $tr(A(\pi_{f_E, p})) = a_p(f_E) = p+1 - N_E(p)$.

Comment: (So my feeling is that there is a typo is the statement of page 23, which I quoted in my question above).

Comment: Dear Watson, I think it would be best to go directly to the source and ask the authors about this, and see if there is a typo.

Comment: On the other hand, their theorem 3.3 only assume "bounded", and would apply to the elliptic curve case (and by exericse 3) in §8.4.4 in Serre's lectures, we get the result with the assumption $\leq 1.4 \sqrt p$ !)